# Understanding Bayes rule

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I know Bayes rule as:

$$P(a \cap b) = P(a \mid b)P(b)$$

But I came across:

$$P( a,z \mid b) = P(a \mid z,b) P(z \mid b)$$

How is the last equation proven?

Comment: I believe it's the same as $P(a \cap z)$

Comment: Let $\tilde P = P(\cdot \mid b)$. Your equation simply tells us that $\tilde P(a \cap z) = \tilde P(a \mid z) \tilde P(z)$, which is something you already know. The only missing step is to show that $\tilde P(a \mid z) = P(a \mid z \cap b)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(a, z \mid b) = \dfrac{P(a, z, b)}{P(b)}$$
$$P(a \mid z, b) = \dfrac{P(a, z, b)}{P(z, b)}$$
$$P(z \mid b) = \dfrac{P(z, b)}{P(b)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $P(C)>0$ and $P(B\cap C)>0$,

$P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A\mid B\cap C)P(B\cap C)=P(A\mid B\cap C)P(B\mid C)P(C)$

Again, $P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A\cap B\mid C)P(C)$

Hence $P(A\cap B\mid C)=P(A\mid B\cap C)P(B\mid C)$

Notation might be different, but I believe you can understand that easily!

Comment: Thanks, your explanation definitely helped

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got your equations mixed up.

$\space \space \space P(a∩b)=P(a∣b)P(b)$

isn't Bayes' Rule, it's  it's the [Law of Conditional Probability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLOCe.png)

Bayes' Rule is  [this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr8bp.png)

$P(A|B) = {{P(B|A)P(A)} \over {P(B)}}$